# Como popular Gráfico ChartJS com VueJs e Axios?

Tags: vue.js, chartjs, axios

não estou conseguindo popular meu gráfico com dados vintos de uma api, podem me ajudar, não sei o que estou fazendo de errado!

```
<template>
<div class="py-1 bg-light px-5">
    <div class="col-12 my-2">                    
        <div class="card shadow-none border-0">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Site Traffic Overview</p>
                <div id="content">
                    <canvas ref="chart"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import ChartJs from '../../domain/Chart';
import ChartService from '../../services/Chart';

export default {
     data () {
    return {
            dados: [],
            month: [],
            views: [],
            dado: {month: '', views: ''}
        }
    },
    mounted(dados){
    listar: () => {
        return http.get('apioculta')        
    }
        ChartService.listar()
        .then(resposta => {
            dados = resposta.data;
            console.log(dados)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
        var chart = this.$refs.chart;
            var ctx = chart.getContext("2d");
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: this.dados.month,                    
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Traffic',
                        data: this.dados.views,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRation: true
                }
            });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: a saída console.log(dados) ta imprimindo corretamente? eu acredito que vc deveria usar this.dados = resposta.data

Comment: Sim, está, no console, tenho todos os dados mostrados, e o gráfico chega a ser montado, mas não carrega as labels e datasets | data, parece ser uma questão de ordem de carregamento que não estou sabendo resolver! Se puder ajudar, grata!

Answer (score 1):

Aconselho usar um pacote chama vue-chartjs https://vue-chartjs.org/ e criar wrappers em cima dele, caso você não queira usar, você pode criar uma variável booleana em data, chamada **hasData: false** e adicionar um **v-if** na *div* do gráfico, **v-if="hasData"**. Assim essa *div* não existirá até os dados serem populados na resposta do serviço, ou seja, dentro do then você seta o **this.hasData = true** após popular a variável **dados**, creio que com isso você resolva o problema.